# How can we update aspnet_Membership table manually in asp.net c#?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, login-control

By default there is only Change Password option in login controls in asp.net.
If someone want to update username, email, security question, security answer then how is it possible.
Which procedures i have to call and how to update these or there are ready-made classes in asp.net to update these fields.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods on the MembershipProvider that you can use, for example

```
Membership.Provider.ResetPassword(string username, string answer);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx